# Upgrade command in UBUNTU

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, upgrade

Whenever  i run the upgrade command in ubuntu linux latest after the update command i get the following errors  !!!
Someone help please [image: my linux terminal]

Comment: i am a newbie to LINUX

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange! Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086)

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting tells you exactly what is wrong. It says "are you root?" And the answer is no, you are not, because you forgot to use [`sudo`](https://acloudguru.com/blog/engineering/linux-commands-for-beginners-sudo) before your last command. If you repeat the command with `sudo` before it, like
`sudo apt --fix-broken install`, then
you are executing it as root, and then you will not get this error.

Answer (score 0):

try `sudo apt --fix-broken install`

Comment: If you could add some reasoning behind this answer, it might help the OP going forward.